# Cutting the beginning of a clause and the relation between "cut", `!`, and `fail`

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

What does it mean to put the cut (`!`) at the very beginning of a clause?

```
  p(X,Y) :- !, q(X), r(X,Y).
```

What is the difference between `!` and  `fail` and how are they related?

thanks.
I'm thinking that for `fail`, the predicate will just "fail" lol which is different from not backtracking? just want to be sure :)

Comment: Yes. `fail` means *fail*. :) That means it will backtrack. But `!` means *cut* and means it will not backtrack further back from that point in the clause. If your example is a single clause predicate, then it doesn't do anything since there's nothing to backtrack to anyway. But if you had another `p(X,Y) :- s(X, Y).` *after* the one you show, then it would not ever be exercised due to the cut in the prior clause (since the prior clause only has variables for arguments and will always match a `p(X, Y)` query before the second clause does).

Comment: You should get good Prolog book (such as *Programming in Prolog* by Clocksin and Mellish for introductory material, or *The Art of Prolog* by Sterling and Shapiro) because they explain these concepts quite thoroughly. :)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, i had actually downloaded that but didn't have a chance to read it lol, but will definitely read it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you use this when you want to make sure that there is no backtracking on a certain combination of variable instantiations. To show some code (borrowed a bit from [the SWI-Prolog implementation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_codes/3):

```
read_lines(In, Ls) :-
    read_line_to_codes(In, Codes),
    read_lines_rest(Codes, In, Ls).

read_lines_rest(end_of_file, _, []) :- !.
read_lines_rest(Codes, In, [Codes|Rest]) :-
    read_line_to_codes(In, New_codes),
    read_lines_rest(New_codes, In, Rest).
```

Now, with these predicates defined, you can read an input stream (a file, for example) to a list of lines. We are using `read_line_to_codes/2` from [`library(readutil)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=readutil). It will unify its second argument with a list of codes representing a line, or the atom `end_of_file` at the end of input.

In the first clause of `read_lines_read/3`, we use unification in the head of the predicate definition. We "demand" that the first argument must be the atom `end_of_file` if we want the predicate to be even considered. When (at the end of input) this clause succeeds, the other possible solution in the second clause of the definition is not taken in consideration, and the predicate succeeds, closing up the list in the third argument.

Here it is used:

```
?- open('shortcut.pl', read, In), read_lines(In, Ls), forall(member(L,Ls), format("~s~n", [L])).
read_lines(In, Ls) :-
    read_line_to_codes(In, Codes),
    read_lines_rest(Codes, In, Ls).

read_lines_rest(end_of_file, _, []) :- !.
read_lines_rest(Codes, In, [Codes|Rest]) :-
    read_line_to_codes(In, New_codes),
    read_lines_rest(New_codes, In, Rest).
% variable instantiations
```

You should notice that the predicate succeeds exactly once. Try removing the cut in the first clause to see what happens.

As for the `fail`, yes, it makes the predicate fail (not succeed). At this point, if there are any choice points left, Prolog will backtrack to the most recent one.